emacs windows gitbash and cmd.exe shells
I have Emacs for windows. I have GITBASH for windows.
My goal: How can I get Emacs to use the GITBASH version of GREP, when I use M-x grep?
NOTE: For various reasons I cannot put "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" in my normal windows path.. (that is where Git Bash places grep.exe)
I have tried "customize variable" but this s not working GRRR... I have:
    '(grep-command "'c:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/grep.exe'  -n "))

with the above, I get c: is not a command
Switching the slashes to \ I get a different error message:

'c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe'  -n target_sources . NUL
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I have tried OTHER variations, and can't seem to figure out how to correctly get the GREP command quoted.
I believe the entire problem is because of the space in the "Program Files" path and quoting this inside of elisp so that it survives the M-x command line generation.

After some more digging... Found the answer.
Instead of specifying the "Long File Name" - you need to use the short filename instead
ie:  '(grep-command "c:\\PROGRA~1\\Git\\usr\\bin\\grep.exe  -n "))
GRR... would be nice if there was an elisp way to do that semi-automatically when it sees spaces in filenames

My elisp times are long gone, but If I would want to use emacs on Windows nowadays, I would first install Cygwin (instead of git-bash), and then use one of the emacs versions which are available with Cygwin. You can then simply use grep, since /usr/bin is in the PATH when you start emacs from one of the shells in Cygwin. If you don't want to work on the command line, install Cygwin/X, where you can run an X-version of emacs.
